# Creating a matrix from a text file - Java

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have this text file:

```
2
2
12
13
23
24
49
59
69
79
```

the first two numbers should be the rows and columns of the matrix, which is 2x2 in this case. My issue that I'm trying to get around is finding a way to include a second 2D array that holds the second matrix.

my code:

```
        Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File("input1.txt"));
        int n1 = fileInput.nextInt();
        int n2 = fileInput.nextInt();
        System.out.print("matrix is " + n1 + "x" + n2 +"\n");

        int [][] firstMatrix = new int [n1][n2];
        int [][] secondMatrix = new int [n1][n2];

        for(int i = 0; i < n1; ++i)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < n2; ++j)
            {
                if(fileInput.hasNextInt())
                {
                    firstMatrix[i][j] = fileInput.nextInt();   
                }                 
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Matrices: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
            {
                System.out.println(firstMatrix[i][j]);
            }
        }
```

it only prints the following:

```
12
13
23
24
```

How do I make it read the next four lines of integers from the file? It would also be helpful to understand how I can make it look something like this:

```
12 13

23 24
```

EDIT: This approach seemed to help with the last question:

```
for(int i=0; i<n1; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<n2; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(firstMatrix[i][j] + " " );
                //System.out.print(secondMatrix[i][j] + " ");

            }
             System.out.println();
        }
```

The only problem I'm facing now is being able to include the four other integers and turn them into a matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just read data for the two arrays from file sequentially, like this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {

    private static void readMatrix(final Scanner scanner, final int[][] matrix) {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; ++j) {
                if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                    matrix[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void displayMatrix(final int[][] matrix) {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));

        final int n1 = scanner.nextInt();
        final int n2 = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.print(String.format("The matrix is %d x %d \n", n1, n2));

        final int[][] firstMatrix = new int[n1][n2];
        final int[][] secondMatrix = new int[n1][n2];

        System.out.println("Reading data to first matrix");
        readMatrix(scanner, firstMatrix);
        System.out.println("Reading data to second matrix");
        readMatrix(scanner, secondMatrix);

        System.out.println("First Matrix");
        displayMatrix(firstMatrix);
        System.out.println("Second Matrix");
        displayMatrix(secondMatrix);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group them to 1 array:

```
int matrixNumb = 2; // number of matrix
int [][][] matrix = new int [matrixNumb][n1][n2];
for (int h = 0; h < matrixNumb; h++)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n1; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n2; ++j)
        {
            if(fileInput.hasNextInt())
            {
                matrix [h][i][j] = fileInput.nextInt();   // read from file
            }                 
        }
    }
}

System.out.println("Matrices: ");
for (int h = 0; h < matrixNumb; h++)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(matrix[h][i][j]);
            System.out.print("\t"); //How do you want to separate columns?
        }
        System.out.print("\r\n"); //How do you want to separate rows?
    }
    System.out.println(); //How do u want to print next matrix?
}
```

I have not compiled or run it, but hope it help.

Comment: I plan on performing martix math on them, I believe it would be easier to have two separate arrays! Thank you for your input, it was helpful. Still having trouble with the second matrix. It prints out `0 0 0 0`

Comment: You can take separate matrix easily: `int[][] firstMaxtrix = matrix[0]` and `int[][] secondMatrix = matrix[1]`

Answer (score -1):

```
 for(int i = 0; i < n1*n1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n2*n2; j++)
        {
            if(fileInput.hasNextInt())
            {
               if(i < n1){
                firstMatrix[i][j] = fileInput.nextInt(); 
                } 
               else 
                  {
                   secondMatrix[i][j] = fileInput.nextInt();
                  }
            }                 
        }
    }
```

You have two matrix of size n*n so you can do like this: